# Rails carrierWave permit parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I am having a problem in uploading an image in Rails 4.2.6 with ruby 2.3.0 and CarrierWave.

I have a podcast model, and when I am trying to create a new model from the form, providing name, description and a .jpg image, I get the following error: `Missing template podcasts/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/Users/mychro94/Desktop/Prova/app/views" * "/Users/mychro94/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-i18n-1.6.1/app/views" * "/Users/mychro94/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.3/app/views"`

If I remove the :image field in

```
def podcast_params
    params.require(:podcast).permit(:name, :description, :image)  
end
```

I don't get that error anymore, but the image is not added to the object created.

The podcast create method is:

```
def create
   @podcast = current_user.podcasts.create(podcast_params)
   if @podcast.save
      redirect_to podcast_path(@podcast)
   end
end
```

and the new.html.erb file is

```
   <%= form_for(@podcast, html: { :multipart => true, id: "input-      container", class: "cf wrapper"}) do |f| %>
   <div id="image-upload">
   <%= f.file_field :image, :required => true %>
   <!--<label for="image" class="inputfile-label">Choose a file</label>-->
   </div>
  <div id="title">
    <%= f.text_field :name,:required => true , placeholder: "Insert Podcast title", class: "border-animation" %>
  </div>

   <div id="description" >
   <%= f.text_area :description, :required => true , placeholder: "Insert Podcast description", class: "border-animation"%>
   </div>

  <div class="btn-bar">

   <div class="right">
    <%= f.submit "Create my podcast",class: "button button-highlight" %>

   </div>
   </div>
   <% end %>
```

this is what I get in the terminal when creating the podcast

```
Started POST "/podcasts" for ::1 at 2018-04-04 09:24:00 +0200
Processing by PodcastsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"wE57eKfcn/74znzOaQ4SBdYf5PSxPFBOZou9EOrhLNHmBzDNBa/nuw7+PJhIa5Lzqb3g55uIjqdhYmrSko+Wew==", "podcast"=>{"image"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fc9043f4fd8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/7y/kh7t8w9j2tzf54_vh32st63r0000gn/T/RackMultipart20180404-50589-qd7z9c.jpg>, @original_filename="pod.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"podcast[image][image]\"; filename=\"pod.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "name"=>"asdas", "description"=>"asdasd"}, "commit"=>"Create my podcast"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 Unpermitted parameter: image
  (0.1ms)  begin transaction
 SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "podcasts" ("name", "description", "artist_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "asdas"], ["description", "asdasd"], ["artist_id", 1], ["created_at", "2018-04-04 07:24:00.672689"], ["updated_at", "2018-04-04 07:24:00.672689"]]
  (0.9ms)  commit transaction
  (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  (0.0ms)  commit transaction
  Redirected to http://localhost:3000/podcasts/28
  Completed 302 Found in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
```

For sure there is something wrong with this

```
"podcast"=>{"image"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fc9043f4fd8
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The error `Missing template podcasts/create, application/create ...` you are seeing is because you haven't handled the **failure** scenario in your `create` action. If `@podcast.save` returns `false` then it will, by rails convention, look for the template with **same name** as the action to render.

You can modify your action as below to *redirect/render* on failure. Most people prefer rendering the same form with errors displayed.

```
def create
  @podcast = current_user.podcasts.create(podcast_params)
  if @podcast.save
    redirect_to podcast_path(@podcast)
  else
    render :new     # Change this according to your will.
  end
end
```

Comment: I get no more that error, and I am redirected again to the new page. in the terminal the transaction is rollback, no further info are given. Still if I get the :image from podcast_params, the podcast is created, but without the image.

Comment: the reason is: unpermitted parameter: image